# one long string => array/list<string> from text within quotes

Tags: c#, string

> 3>>asdf3424"THIS TEXT".,.<<<>>3asfdf"THISTOO"6575tsdfbxbxcv"ANDTHIS",,p-01fa

To an array or list of `{ "THIS TEXT", "THISTOO, "ANDTHIS" }`

Does anyone have an idea on how to *efficiently* do this?

Comment: If the string  has unpaired quotes, what is the desired behavior?

Comment: Define "efficiently" - versus the inefficient ways you have tried.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni The data will always be well formed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\"".+?\""")
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(m => m.Value)
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: I approve of the use of regex for clearly stating what's being done (wait, jwz just heard us taking his name in vain).... BUT the 'efficiency' pseudo-constraint of the question and 'guaranteed' well-formedness of the input make me consider the possibility that Mac's simple while loop might be equally appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you read each character at a time and look for a quotation mark, then read the following into a char array until you find a another quotation mark, then continue looking for one, you can have a list of char arrays that are easily transferable to string.

It should just be a simple while(still characters to be read).

Answer (score 1):

If you have some big string maybe like this :

```
string str = "hello,hi,bye";
```

you may split it by comma something like this:

```
string[] breakups = str.Split(new[] {',' });
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there is a lot of garbage around the quotations(his delimiter) that would be picked up by this method.